# How do I mock an Axios Instance that is imported from a separate module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, enzyme

In my react component I have:

```js
import AxiosInstance from '../../common/ApiHandler'
```

where in ApiHandler.js I create an AxiosInstance

```js
AxiosInstance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

export default AxiosInstance;
```

I am trying to write a unit test for a function where this AxiosInstance does a post request.
Should I mock axios itself or should I mock the AxiosInstance imported into the react component?
How would I mock it so it returns some mock data?

I originally tried the code below but this did not seem to return the data the way I wanted.

```js
jest.mock("axios", () => {
  return {
    create: jest.fn(() => {
      post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(data: {mocked_data}))
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend creating mocks for the system under test. Your component doesn't know about `axios`, only the `AxiosInstance` so that is what you should mock

```js
import AxiosInstance from "../../common/ApiHandler";

jest.mock("../../common/ApiHandler", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: { // add mock functions for whatever methods your component uses
    post: jest.fn(),
  },
}));
```

In your tests you can configure the responses. For example

```js
// A successful response
AxiosInstance.post.mockResolvedValue({ data: mocked_data });

// A failed response
AxiosInstance.post.mockRejectedValue({ status: 400 });
```

---

Regarding `__esModule: true`, see [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)...

> When using the `factory` parameter for an ES6 module with a default export, the `__esModule: true` property needs to be specified.

---

You could also create a more general [manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks) of `ApiHandler` that can be re-used in any of your tests

```js
// common/__mocks__/ApiHandler.js

export default {
  get: jest.fn(),
  post: jest.fn(),
};
```

Then your tests can use a simpler mock without a factory function

```js
import AxiosInstance from "../../common/ApiHandler";

jest.mock("../../common/ApiHandler");
```